# I'm not sure if "'s" is valid in this sentence

Tags: possessives

While writing an academic paper on chemistry, I have to write a section, entitled:

Cumene hydroperoxide's dissociative adsorption.

My question is, would it be correct to write it without 's ? In other words, which one is more grammatically correct? The previous one or one of the following:

Cumene hydroperoxide dissociative adsorption.

Dissociative adsorption of cumene hydroperoxide.

My first tongue is Spanish, and I'm afraid the third option may be a too literal translation and will not sound as proper english.

Comment: Definitely leave in the 's' as is, BUT I would recommend the last option: "Dissociative Absorption of Cumene Hydroperoxide" -- In addition, make sure to capitalize every word that isn't a preposition or a conjunction if this is the title of a section.

Comment: Nothing wrong with either the first or the third version.  The second is only proper if treated as technical jargon vs "properly formed" English.

Comment: You are best going with / accepting ghostarbeiter's answer here. It is easily the best.

Comment: #3 is easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cumene hydroperoxide's dissociative adsorption.

is considered correct, since both *Cumene hydroperoxide* and *dissociative adsorption* are nouns. 
It is similiar to *The chair's leg*. However, there is some discussion on this, so you may want to avoid using it.

The third sentence,

> Dissociative adsorption of cumene hydroperoxide.

is also correct. For the reason that the correctness of the first sentence is sometimes disputed, I would prefer this one.

Answer (score 4):

The third option is best. As a matter of style the "apostrophe-s" form is rarely used with long compound words. It would sound particularly odd in formal academic writing.

The possessive apostrophe-s form is most natural with simple animate nouns and ownership or parts of a whole: *John's dog*, *the dog's left front paw*. It is less common with inanimate nouns and mere properties: for instance, *the color of the sky on Mars* sounds far more natural than using apostrophe-s.

Regarding the second option, sometimes nouns can be used in this way, for instance: *Carbon dioxide emission is a factor in global warming*. But when both the first part and the second part are two-word phrases, it sounds clumsy and is best rephrased using "of".